# One-time advice

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros, advice

I've been trying to a macro to **put one-time advice on a function**.

What I mean by one-time advice is **advice which removes itself after it is called** – so that when you add the advice and run the original function, the advice runs, but if you run the function again, the advice is gone.

My current (non-working) definition is

```
(defmacro add-one-time-advice (symbol where function &optional props)
  `(let ((ad-sym (make-symbol "advice")))
    (fset ad-sym (symbol-function ,function))
    (advice-add ad-sym :after (lambda () (advice-remove ,symbol ad-sym)))
    (advice-add ,symbol ,where ad-sym ,props)))
```

This throws no errors, but the advice doesn't remove itself.

If my approach is okay, **how can I fix it**, and if it's not, **what's the cleanest way to implement this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a macro for this.  And you don't need (but you can certainly use) lexical binding.

```el
;; Without lexical binding:
;;
(defun advise-once (symbol where function &optional props)
  (advice-add symbol :after `(lambda (&rest _) (advice-remove ',symbol ',function)))
  (advice-add symbol where function props))

;; With lexical binding:
;;
(defun advise-once (symbol where function &optional props)
  (advice-add symbol :after (lambda (&rest _) (advice-remove symbol function)))
  (advice-add symbol where function props))

(advise-once 'backward-word :before (lambda (_) (message "Eureka!")))
```

The reason you do not need lexical binding is that you are interested, when the function (lambda form) is used, only in the **values** of `symbol` and `function`, such as they were at the time the lambda-form list was created. You do not need **variables** `symbol` and `function` when the lambda form is used.

The use of the backquote syntax *constructs a list* that is a lambda form, where the **values** of `symbol` and `function` have been substituted in place of those variables.

Using lexical binding has the advantage that the lambda form can be compiled, because it is recognized by the compiler as a function, whereas in the case of using the backquote syntax all the compiler sees is code that constructs a list.

Comment: I'm getting too macro-happy! This teaches me to try using a function first... I think the insight here is to use another advice to remove the first advice from the function (instead of advising the advice). Anyway, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks OK, actually (I would get rid of the call to `symbol-function`, tho).

My crystal ball tells me that maybe you get bitten by dynamic scoping: your code relies on lexical-scoping for its use of `ad-sym` from within the `lambda`, so it's indispensable that `lexical-binding` be non-nil in the code that *uses* this macro.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the proposed solution lets the function advised.
The `:after` advice to remove the original advice is not removed, so `(advice-remove ...)` remains being executed.

Here is an alternative solution "modifying the advice". Now, no advice is left, but it just works for interactive advises.
Hopefully someone would fix it :)

```
(defun advice-once (symbol where function &optional props)
  (let ((new-function (intern (concat (symbol-name function) "-advice-once"))))
    (fset new-function `(lambda (&rest _)
                   ;; (,function)
                   ;; (funcall ',function)
                   ;; (command-execute ',function)
                   (call-interactively ',function)
                   (advice-remove ',symbol #',new-function)))
    (advice-add symbol where new-function props)))

(defun eureka nil
  (interactive)
 (message "Eureka!"))

(advice-once 'backward-word :before #'eureka)
```

Following OP code, here is a version "advising the advice". The code is more simple, `symbol` does not remains advised and it works for pretty much any advising function. But, the advising function `function` remains advised, which can not be solved.

```
(defun advice-once (symbol where function &optional props)
    (advice-add function :after `(lambda (&rest _) (advice-remove ',symbol #',function)))
    (advice-add symbol where function props))
```